# Verification of an equation?

Tags: covariance, conditional-expectation

Suppose $Z$ is a binary (0 or 1) variable. I do not know how to prove the following

$$
\frac{E[Y \mid Z=1]-E[Y \mid Z=0]}{E[D \mid Z=1]-E[D \mid Z=0]} =\frac{\operatorname{cov}(Y, Z)}{\operatorname{cov}(D, Z)} 
$$

Comment: You could start with $E[XZ] = P[Z=1]E[Y \mid Z =1]$ and $E[X]= P[Z=1]E[Y \mid Z =1]+P[Z=0]E[Y \mid Z =0]$ and $E[Z] = P[Z=1]$  and  $P[Z=0]=1- P[Z=1])$.  Expand the quotient of covariances and cancel common factors

Comment: @Henry Got it. Thanks a lot, Henry!